# How to install LuaCOM

Tags: lua, luarocks, luacom

I downloaded the LuaCOM package, searched around it for a while, but couldn't find any hints as to how to install it

I know you can download Luaforwindows, but that has a slightly outdated version of Lua, and I don't want to use it.

I then went searching for Luarocks, and I encountered the same problem. The Wiki states that a INSTALL.bat should be present, but if it is I can't find it.

So how do I install Lua plugins like LuaCOM and Luarocks?

I would like to know if there is a generic method for installing all Lua plugins, or if there is a specific install method for each plugin.

If there is a specific install method for LuaCOM I would like to know what it is. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Okay, I figured out how to install LuaRocks, but it keeps throwing an error and it's because there's a file `unix.config` missing. I tried doing `./configure`, but all windows returned me was the not recognized command error. How do I fix this?

Comment: http://luadist.org/ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can install LuaCOM via LuaRocks or LuaDist if you don't want to use LuaforWindows.

**LuaRocks** (http://luarocks.org/releases/ <- win32 for Windows)

http://www.luarocks.org/en/Installation_instructions_for_Windows 
(install.bat is only in win32-version)

```
luarocks install luacom
```

**LuaDist** (http://luadist.org/)

```
luadist install luacom
```

Comment: But, how do you install LuaRocks once you've downloaded it? I don't quite understand exactly what the instruction manual is saying